# Justify text in Streamlit

Tags: streamlit

I am using the `streamlit_scrollable_textbox` library in streamlit.

I can't find a way to justify the text.

```
import streamlit as st
import streamlit_scrollable_textbox as stx

Purpose = '<div style="text-align: Center; font-size:30px"><span 
   
style="font-family: Georgia;">Purpose</div></span>'
st.write(Purpose, unsafe_allow_html=True)

st.text("")

Responsibilities = """Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the p"""

stx.scrollableTextbox(Responsibilities,height = 450)

st.text("")

styled_button = '<div style="text-align:center">' \
            '<button style="background-color:white; color:black; 
            border:2px black; border-radius:5px; padding:10px">' \
            'Click to proceed' \
            '</button>' \
            '</div>'
st.write(styled_button, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Mazen Saie! Can you add the code you are using and a screenshot of the resulting Streamlit app?

Comment: Code and image added, thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

It seems not possible using the package `streamlit-scrollable-textbox`. You can [open an issue](https://github.com/RobertoFN/streamlit-scrollable-textbox/issues/new) on the GitHub repository to ask the creator to add this functionality.

It is however possible to do it without this package. You can use `streamlit.components.v1` instead with a style `<div style="text-align: justify;">`, like this:

```py
import streamlit as st
import streamlit.components.v1 as components
import random
import string

st.set_page_config(layout="wide")

# Tools to generate random text
# Instead of Lorem Ipsum, because otherwise it is too long 
# for Stackoverflow answers and makes the code unreadable.
def generate_random_paragraph(n_words):
    def generate_random_word(max_length=15):
        r = random.randint(1, max_length)
        return "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(r)).capitalize()
    return " ".join(generate_random_word() for _ in range(n_words))

# Generating a long text made up of 5 paragraphs with 200 words each.
text = "\n".join([generate_random_paragraph(n_words=200) for _ in range(5)])
text = text.replace("\n", "<br>")

components.html(
    f"""
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <div class="card">
        <div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div style="text-align: justify;">
                    {text}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    """,
    height=450,
    scrolling=True,
)
```

It gives a justified text with a scrolling bar:

[image: Long Lorem Ipsum-like justified]

---

The code I provided was inspired by [this page](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/components/components-api#stcomponentsv1html) in the Streamlit documentation about components.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback, is there any limitation on the text length? im planning to use for terms and conditions so i need no limitations.

Comment: I just tried with 1000 paragraphs of 2000 words each and it worked well.